# Complete utter wits end, all solutions online those not work for me for the Error "Session 'app': Error Installing APKs"

Tags: android, android-studio

Utter Wits end. Tried all solutions: clean build, sync project files with gradle, build Bundles, Build APKs, disable and re-enable instant runs etc.

Followed Exact steps outlined in other threads/ posts but still couldn't get the app to run on my physical Samsung Galaxy S7 phone. It was working fine previously, but now couldn't get it to work. App still able to open on Emulators though.

Needed to test out gyroscope and accelerometer sensors on a physical phone which emulators can't achieve as intent.

Would like to seek help from the community regarding this matter. Any idea where it has gone wrong?  I have already updated my compilesdkverison and targetsdkversion in the  module:app build.gradle scripts. Tried almost everything that I can think of but to no avail. Hoping to see the light and receive enlightenment from the community as I'm a novice in Android Studio.

[image]

PS: By the way, how do people add actual iamges to the post, itseems like the only way i can show an image is in the form of a hyperlink away from current page. Is there a way to just put the image directly in the post here?

[image]

Comment: Here are a couple of things that you can check.
1. Need to check if there is enough space on the phone?
2. Enabling (install from unknown sources) on your phone

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is not enough space on your phone. Try making some space on your internal memory.

Comment: from the error message itself, seems to be the case, but that is far from true. Infact I have 465MB of memory available. Hence I'm puzzled as to why there isn't enough memory space? Surely the Android app does not require 400MB worth of memory space right? See above original post, I added a second Hyperlink for the image of my available phone memory storage space.

Comment: Did you install it successfully prior to this?

Comment: Yes I did perform all installations. I'm using the most updated Android Studio Version 3.4. I don't think installation is what's causing the problem. The fact that I'm able to run the app smoothly without facing any problems on my emulator proves that there is nothing wrong with the app.  I have already Checked apks, sdks, bundle, also checked compileSdkVersion targetSdkVersion minSdkVersion in my gradle script to make sure that they areare in the correct configuration settings and are compatible.

Comment: I suspect the following is happening.

https://www.easeus.com/android-data-recovery/fix-installation-error-install-failed-insufficient-storage.html

If you don't have a rooted device try a device reboot or uninstall of any existing version of the app you're trying to install